# Witchcraft in JavaScript manipulating DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have 3 HiddenFor Razor Strings on the HTML which will pass values to the Model C#.

Then I have a JavaScript with three Dropzones (js lib for drag and drop). At this point there will be three "remove events" which will populate that hiddenforValues.

To do this I tested 3 different syntaxes:

```
document.getElementById().value
document.querySelector().value
$('#Element').value
```

but I noticed something strange:
for the first two hiddenfor the querySelector and the jQuery method works fine, however for the third one only `document.getElementById` will work (otherwise value will be sent as null).
At same time `document.getElementByID` is not recognized if I use this more than once.

So if I use jQuery for two of them and `document.getElementById` for the last one this will work fine.

The question is... why?

The only thing different is that third string have "," inside.

jQuery doesn't work with special characters or something like that?

My code works but I'm just curious about that buggy functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use `$('#Element').val()` instead.

`$(*)` returns a `jQuery collection` that has many `methods` but no `option` like `value`.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` and `$()` both accept a css selector string for identifying a target. In CSS, `,` separates selectors.

Thus, `$('#a,b')` will look for an element with id "a" *or* a `b` element, whereas `document.getElementById('a,b')` will yield an element with the id "a,b".

To simulate this behavior in jQuery, you'd need to write `$('*[id="a,b"]');`

Comment: Thanks, after some tests i can confirm the next:
1) getElementById()  could not work in newest Browsers.
2) querySelector() and $() could not work in older Browsers.
3) The real problem here is that i created a var with same name (document) in my javascript. This will not tell you that your overrithing that special word. That was causing the bug. Renaming the variable fixed the problem.